# How to get first occurrence of each duplicate in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, duplicates

I have an array of objects:

```
array =
[{:id=>433, :name=>"test 1", :type=>"Staff"},
 {:id=>434, :name=>"test 2", :type=>"Guard"},
 {:id=>435, :name=>"test 3", :type=>"Office boy"},
 {:id=>471, :name=>"test 1", :type=>"Staff"},
 {:id=>473, :name=>"test 2", :type=>"Guard"}]
```

Some `:type` values occur more than once. For each duplicate `:type` value, I want to retrieve that type's first object.

The expected output is:

```
[{:id=>433, :name=>"test 1", :type=>"Staff"},
 {:id=>434, :name=>"test 2", :type=>"Guard"}]
```

A hash with type "Office boy" is not included because that type only occurs once.

Comment: You want to group same type and return it?

Comment: I want array with same type

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Same type as what? Do you want groups or just the hashes with a given `type:` key? Can you give an example of the desired result?

Comment: There is an key in object type. I want the object of array who has same type key

Comment: This still makes zero sense as its just jumbled gargon. Thats an array of hashes and unless you can actually tell us what the desired result is I don't think we can help you.

Comment: Like i want if object have admin type and staff multiple time I want those object only

Comment: check out my answer and let me know whether you want this.

Comment: Would you mind adding the expected output (as code) to your question?

Comment: I just want only [{:id=>433, :name=>"test 1", :type=>"Staff"},
 {:id=>434, :name=>"test 2", :type=>"Guard"}],

Comment: @smith your result only contains types "Staff" and "Guard". Why is type "Office boy" missing?

Comment: I just only want duplicate type result

Comment: Hi smith, I have updated the answer according to your requirement, check out.

Comment: @smith oh okay, so you want each type's first hash but only for hashes whose `:type` value occurs more than once, right?

Comment: yes I want this

Comment: @smith I've updated your question accordingly. You might want to take a few minutes next time to explain what you want more thoroughly.

Comment: I edited your question simply to assign the given array to a variable (`array`, the name chosen by @Rajagopalan). That way readers can refer to the array by that variable in answers and comments without having to define it. In general, it's helpful to assign each input in an example to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array = [{ :id => 433, :name => "test 1", :type => "Staff" },
         { :id => 434, :name => "test 2", :type => "Guard" },
         { :id => 435, :name => "test 3", :type => "Office boy" },
         { :id => 471, :name => "test 1", :type => "Staff" },
         { :id => 473, :name => "test 2", :type => "Guard" }]

result = array.group_by { |hash| hash[:type] }.values.filter_map do |value|
  value.first if value.count > 1
end

p result
```

Output

```
[{:id=>433, :name=>"test 1", :type=>"Staff"}, {:id=>434, :name=>"test 2", :type=>"Guard"}]
```

Comment: Where are we storing the new result?

Comment: It just return this [{:id=>433, :name=>"test 1", :type=>"Staff"}].

Comment: sorry, it still giving me same result twice

Comment: [{:id=>433, :name=>"test 1", :type=>"Staff"}, {:id=>433, :name=>"test 1", :type=>"Staff"}]

Comment: I did. I paste the code and in return i am getting the output just i post

Comment: sorry my mistake, It's working

Comment: You can delete all the comment here.

Comment: You can use `filter_map` rather than `map { }.compact`. You could also avoid the disposable Array created by `values` by just iterating over the `Hash` e.g. `array.group_by { |hash| hash[:type] }.filter_map {|_,v| v.first if v.size > 1 }`

Comment: You really should adopt @engineersmnky's suggestion to get rid of `compact`, both to avoid the extra step and to rid your code of one of Ruby's ugliest methods (my opinion, true).

Comment: Yes you guys are right, filter map is the right option in this place

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that uses [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally).

```
types_count = array.map { |h| h[:type] }.tally
  #=> {"Staff"=>2, "Guard"=>2, "Office boy"=>1}
```

```
array.select do |h|
  type = h[:type]
  keep = types_count[type] > 1
  types_count[type] = 0
  keep
end
  #=> [{:id=>433, :name=>"test 1", :type=>"Staff"},
  #    {:id=>434, :name=>"test 2", :type=>"Guard"}]
```

Comment: While I understand this was written in such a way as to be easily comprehensible all those lines make me itch inside . `types_count.delete(h[:type])&.>(1)`

Comment: @engineersmnky, I agree and was looked for something more elegant but didn't think of using `delete`. A variant of your suggestion is `types_count.delete(h[:type]).to_i > 1`.

Comment: True but safe nav is going to be [slightly] more performant than than casting `nil` to an `Integer`. Even though `0` is an immediate there is the overhead of message transmission. Since safe nav is not a method call it avoids this overhead but in this case the improvement is infinitesimal. Another option would be to combine the conditional and assignment one could use `&&` for this although `and` would probably be more appropriate. `types_count[type] > 1 and types_count[type] = 0`.

Comment: @engineersmnky, that cannot be proven, as "performant" is a nonsense word, even though it was listed by the OED in 2018 as one of its "new words" (both a noun and an adjective), though the definitions do not appear to have made it to print yet.  The Cambridge University Press defines performant as, "working in an effective way" (adjective only), which does not provide an ordering when comparisons are made. The "word" makes my skin crawl. I hate it!

Comment: Hahaha very well. It will be more efficient in time and resources based on the current implementation of YARV. Words have the meaning one attributes to them in context and now I wish I had also used the term "comprehendable" in my first comment 